Ellipse Pro Issues since Driver Upgrade
Back in '21 downloaded the latest driver
Eaton UPS Companion (deprecated link now)
for the 5S 1200AU (P348G35D92), and received the following error on this rig with W10 20H2:

There was also a hang-during-download error when attempting to upgrade through the old version (1.04), previously.
When that version was uninstalled, there was no way to connect with the UPS.
Installing the UPS Companion (euc_win_2_00_025.exe) and clicking the "Finish" button in the dialog, the app froze. Consequently, the Eaton UPS Companion Service did not start, and on a manual attempt to do so there was:
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Right now, the device is still not connecting with symptoms as per above.
In Control Panel (Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers), the device is listed as a Battery/Input Device, "Ellipse Pro".
In Devices, "American Power Conversion USB UPS" is not present any more.
Used USBDeview to clean up unwanted USB devices, the properties page for "Ellipse Pro" in there shows the VendorID, USB Version, 1.1, USB Class, 3.0, correct serial number: PNNNNNNNN, but ffff as the ProductID.
In Devices, the Eaton UPS 0463-L is "working", there are messages indicating things are not well:
Event 20003: Driver Management has concluded the process to add Service libusb0 for ... with the following status: 0.
Event 430 Device USB\VID_0463&PID_FFFF\P348G35D92 requires further installation.
Event 442 USB\VID_0463 "not migrated due to partial or ambiguous match"

After removal, a typical install sequence goes like:
Event 442   Not migrated
Event 400   Configured
Event 410 Started
Event 442   Not migrated
Event 20003 Registry Issue

libusb0.sys "checks out" (don't have InfVerif), as does oem3.inf, so they may not be the cause for the failure. It may be some kind of misconfiguration of USB 1.1, not easy to diagnose though.

As a matter of interest, the exact same issue was repro'd over at Reddit and Tom's Hardware, the alternative suggested from the latter, UPSmart, hasn't worked to date, it may require more tinkering though. There are other UPS management or control tools, some using NUT.
Installed the UPS Companion on a different, newer W11 machine, an HP Elite in fact. Succeeded this time, mostly. The UPS Companion icon is invisible in the systray, and upon clicking the "Check for Updates ..." button, there pops up:

"The Eaton web server is unreachable"

Looks very much like an issue with a previous update in W10 then, whatever system component "Labels" labels.js is expecting is not present.
